# What am I missing with this simple jquery / json function?

Tags: jquery, json

I have a simple ajax query to a file which basically returns in JSON error or success.

ie:

```
{"error":"1"}{"error_msg":" Invalid Expiry Date. Your credit card has not been billed for this transaction."}
```

The issue however is that even though I'm getting this json data return from my ajax post, I can't seem to access the data at all.

My jquery looks something like this:

```
     $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'process_sale.php',
          data: $(this).serialize(), 
          cache: false,
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data) {

            if(data['success']=='1'){

                alert('hi');

                $('#feedback').html('<strong>Congratulations</strong');

            }

            if(data['error']=='1') {

                alert('hi');

                $('#feedback').html(data['error_msg']);


            }

                   // this following alert does nothing, because its empty even if the json 
                   // returns what I pasted above example result.

                   alert(data['error'] + ' ' + data['success']);

          }
        });
```

None of the alerts will do anything.

Am I missing something really obvious here? I can't seem to wrap my head around why this isn't working as it seems to be fairly identical to other code I have working.

Comment: Does the AJAX response also return an error (non 2xx) status? If so, your success callback won't catch it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to parse invalid JSON -- you have two adjacent JSON objects in your example. You need to either place them in an array, or make them one object if you want JS to understand them:

```
// You want this:
{"error":"1", // note , not {}
 "error_msg":" Invalid Expiry Date. "+
              "Your credit card has not been billed for this transaction."}

// or this (notice the `,` and the `[`, and `]`)
[{"error":"1"},{"error_msg":" Invalid Expiry Date. Your credit card has not been billed for this transaction."}]
```

Based on the rest of your code, I would wager that the first one will meet your needs better. You're probably going to prefer to access the error message data['error'] and not data[0]['error']

Answer (score 1):

The json data should like this :

```
{"error":"1","message":"This is an error message"}
```

Ajax call :

```
$.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'process_sale.php',
          data: $(this).serialize(), 
          cache: false,
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data) {
            if (data != null){
            if(data.error=='0'){

                alert('Success');

                $('#feedback').html('<strong>Congratulations</strong');

            }

            if(data.error=='1') {

                alert('Error occurred');

                $('#feedback').html(data.mesage);


            }
           }else{
                //do something with NULL
           } 

          }
        });
```